# How to clean up my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm trying to do a blog post's comments section where comments are listed below the post.

I have `Posts` and `PostComments` classes

I have `posts/show.html.erb` to show the blog post and I have made a `post_comments/_post_comment.html.erb` partial to render a comment

in `posts/show.html.erb` i have the following:

```
<% @post.post_comments.each do |comment| %> 
    <%= render :partial => '/post_comments/post_comment', :locals=>{ :comment => comment } %>
<% end %>
```

Is there any way to move that loop out of the view and into a method in the controller? I want to call will_paginate on it, and I don't think I can do that if the logic is in the view like it is now.

Comment: I don't use ruby, but your current method seems to me to be the best way to iterate content with a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want call will_paginate on it do

```
<% @post.post_comments.paginate(params[:page], params[:per_page]).each do |comment| %> 
    <%= render :partial => '/post_comments/post_comment', :locals=>{ :comment => comment } %>
<% end %>
```

And it's better to define in your controller are instance attribute to this return

```
@post_comments = @post.post_comments.paginate(params[:page], params[:per_page])
```

And in you view

```
<% @post_comments.each do |comment| %> 
    <%= render :partial => '/post_comments/post_comment', :locals=>{ :comment => comment } %>
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate(@post_comments) %>
```

In this case, this loop is only to record really view. Not all records.

Comment: bah, that makes so much more sense than the thought process i was trying to follow. thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Try the render partial collection :

```
<%= render :partial    => '/post_comments/post_comment', 
           :collection => @post_comments  %>
```

This will render `/post_comments/_post_comment.erb` and pass the local variable `post_comment` to the template for display. An iteration counter will automatically be made available to the template with a name of the form post_comment_counter.

If you have the page, page size parameters available then you can call paginate directly in the view.

```
<%= render :partial    => '/post_comments/post_comment', 
           :collection => @post.post_comments.paginate(:page => params[:page]) %>
```